# JavaScript Short Circuit Logic

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

After seeing some examples online, I've collected two different explanations:

> > Ex: var x = A || B;
> >
> > 1. If A exists and B does not, left side is returned.
> > 2. If A exists and B exists , return right side (last evaluated value).

Based on that logic, I would assume that x would return: `v.item(0).click()`. But when testing it x first returned B then A, aka fired B then fired A as well. Why? (http://jsfiddle.net/nysteve/QHumL/59/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="indeed-apply-button" onclick="alert('BOOM BUTTON');">boo</div>
<div class='view_job_link' onclick="alert('BOOM LINK');">boo</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var v = document.getElementsByClassName('view_job_link');
var i = document.getElementsByClassName('indeed-apply-button');
var x = v.item(0).click() || i.item(0).click();
```

**EDIT 1:02 PM 10/10/2013**

Did not mention my true intentions, but based on the answer and discussion, my goal was essentially to convert the following piece of code into the JavaScript code I originally mentioned.

```
var v = document.getElementsByClassName('view_job_link');
var i = document.getElementsByClassName('indeed-apply-button');
if(v){v.item(0).click();}
else if(i){i.item(0).click();}
else{}
```

In the code above, how would you read `if(v){v.item(0).click();}` vs. the short-circuit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "exists" and "does not exist", but the use of `||` to do short circuit evaluation checks for truthyness of the values. So it's checking for the truthyness of the result of calling `.click()`

Comment: if A is something, then it doesn't matter what B is or isn't...

Comment: +1 for clearly stating your question, posting your relevant html and JavaScript code, and including a working fiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of your two descriptions are accurate.

```
var x = A || B;
```

What that does is:

1. Evaluate "A". *Call the result V<sub>A</sub>.*
2. If *V<sub>A</sub>* is not `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, `false`, or the empty string, then the value of the overall expression is *V<sub>A</sub>* and evaluation stops.
3. Evaluate "B". *Call the result V<sub>B</sub>.* That value, *V<sub>B</sub>*, is the value of the expression.

Your test code first tests the return value of calling the "click" function on the first element and then the second.  Those functions both return `undefined`, so the subexpressions on both sides of the `||` are evaluated. That is, the first call gets *V<sub>A</sub>* and it's `undefined`, so that means that the other side will be evaluated too, and that'll be the value of the expression. (It's going to come out `undefined`.)

*edit* — OK now that you've added more to the answer, I think I see what you're up to.

In your actual code (or, I guess, the sample code that's closer to reality), you've got:

```
if(v){v.item(0).click();}
else if(i){i.item(0).click();}
else{}
```

That means something quite different than:

```
var x = v.item(0).click() || i.item(0).click();
```

Note that in the `if` statement version, it's explicitly checking "v".  A test like that will perform a "truthy/falsy" test on the value of "v". In this case, it's really checking to make sure that "v" isn't either `null` or `undefined`.  In the `||` version, however, there's no such explicit test for the "goodness" of variable "v"; it's just used directly. (If it happens to be `null` there, that'd result in a runtime  error.)

A version of the actual code using `||` and `&&` is possible, but in my opinion the existing code is clearer.  However, just for discussion purposes, you could replace the `if` version with:

```
v && (v.item(0).click(), true) || i && i.item(0).click();
```

Personally I think that looks kind-of ugly.

Comment: Following that logic, why do both A and B fire if the entire expression evaluates to 'undefined.' Shouldn't this throw a flag/warning and not execute at all?

Comment: @brooklynsweb no, that's just not how JavaScript works. Both of them fire because after evaluating "A" and determining that it's "falsy", it *has* to evaluate "B"; that's the whole point of the `||` operator.

Comment: This may be a bit off topic —but relating -what is the difference between 'falsy' and 'false?' If 'falsy' is like 'false', then should it not fire A and stop (based on your item 2 description —it being a 'false(y)' like value)? Pardon if the question sounds childish; I get the gist of your answer to my general question though. As an example, here's another version of my code [link]http://jsfiddle.net/nysteve/QHumL/60/. The expression "if(v)," does it not mean "if it is true that v exists?" I guess I was trying to use the SC to compress this version.

Comment: Also why could I not use [@ + Pointy] before (now it works: @Pointy) to address you Pointy? Is it because you've been the only person making comments?

Comment: SO is weird about the "@" things; I don't fully understand it. Anyway, "falsy" and "truthy" are just shorthand for the rules about how values are interpreted as `true` or `false` in certain circumstances.  In the evaluation of `||`, things only stop after doing "A" when the value is **not** "falsy".

Comment: I see, @Pointy, please look over my original question again as I added my main intention.

Comment: Ah, OK thanks - that helps me see what you're trying to do.  I'll add to the answer.